# Display array objects in table/grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render my array objects into a table/gird format with headers for each column. So far I have them all rendered with a flat list and the output looks like this:

[image: flat-list display]

My code:

```
<ViewContainer>
    <Text style = {styles.titleText}>
    Approval  Diameter
    </Text>
    <ScrollView maximumZoomScale = {5} scrollEnabled = {true} minimumZoomScale = {1} zoomScale = {.8}>
     <FlatList
            data = {this.state.data}
            keyExtractor = {(x, i) => i.toString()}
            renderItem ={({item}) =>
                <Text style = {styles.itemText}>
                {item.approval}           {item.diameter} {"\n"}
                </Text>
            }
        />
        <Text style = {styles.countryErrorText}>{this.state.countrySelected}</Text>
    </ScrollView>    
</ViewContainer>
```

As you can see, this does not look good and is hard to read. Putting it into a table or grid with header columns would solve the issue.

Any help would be great.